# Heroku's slow time-to-first-byte

Tags: node.js, heroku

Due to circumstances beyond my control, the demo app I'm trying to host on Heroku loads a lot of files synchronously. Some or just JS/XML, others are JSON files based on real data sets. Because I do not need all datasets, some of these results in `404`'s (as per the screenshot). I'm talking about 100 files altogether.

Because this is on Heroku (US) at the moment and I am in Australia, this process takes a very long time. The database results are fast. ~28ms for them to be delivered to my browser. This is only an issue with static content which is delivered using Express:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public'), {
    maxAge: 86400000 * 7
}));
```

I have read some of the other questions and answers on this site and they do not seem help.

[image]

So here the wait time is 383ms, and this is consistent with the other files. So, I sit and wait ~380ms * 100 for the app to load.

Some more info: it's a single hobby dyno, but I'm the only one looking at the page at the moment. CPU and memory are well under control. It is not a dyno sleep issue.

I have no control over the synchronous load, but I'm able to change the Heroku set up or hosting. Does anyone have any good advice on how to minimise this?